# Handling mysql deadlock

Tags: python, mysql, database-performance

I have the following SQL statement:

```
self.cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO main_iteminstance (...) VALUES (...)''')
```

This operation runs several million times in a two-hour script. However, about once every ten script runs, it runs into a deadlock:

```
OperationalError: (1205, 'Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction')
```

How should I deal with this? My thinking was to do the following --

```
while True:
    try:
        self.cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO main_iteminstance (...) VALUES (...)''')
    except MySQLdb.OperationalError:
        continue
    else:
        break
```

Is this the best pattern to use? Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What about using a retries parameter under the OperationalError and increment it as it fails?

Comment: @spicyramen could you please explain what you mean here?

Comment: When the script fails that specific transaction and reach OperationalError, since you are using continue and return the control to the beginning of the while loop, I would use a retries parameter flag when we hit that exception and that will attempt the SQL transaction X amount of times before consider it a failure. Other option will be put it to sleep and then retry.

Comment: @spicyramen -- makes sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you break your values into something like this?

```
INSERT INTO main_item_instance (...) VALUE (...), (....), ....
```

Do you have to do individual inserts or can you do one big insert at the end of the script?

Comment: yes it wouldn't be possible to do this at the end. This is sort of 'streaming ingest' with one item/file at a time.

Comment: I should've made that a comment, not an answer